# How to get file/folder size with SSH on linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using SSH to connect to a CentOS server and I want to get the file in mb of some files and folders, how can I do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use the du command

```
du -m filename
```

Comment: If you use `du -h` instead, it'll chose (and print) the appropriate units.

Comment: If you use du -ms folder, it will report the size of the folder contents.

Comment: Is there a way where we can see the units - example mb, kb or any other information?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid wc -c

Answer (score 24):

```
 du -msh FolderName
```

will get the size with units. Unlike using -h, this will show a single size, while -h shows all the individual files within the folder.
e.g.

```
349M    FolderName
```

Comment: much better than accepted solution

Comment: du -sh /yourpath/* to list all directories in a given path and summarized sizes of their contents

Answer (score 13):

`du` is the primary tool for this, but if you're looking for something more interactive, I quite like `ncdu`

[image: ncdu_screenshot]